# URL Hyperlinking

Tags: browser

I would like to have the URL from an attribute (in the attribute table) as a 'hotlink' wherein you can click on the URL and it opens the browser with the data.  As it is right now, I'm having to "toggle edit" the attribute table, R-click on the feature, open form, and copy/paste the URL into a browser.  I don't write python code so does anyone have a quick workaround for me? (I can paste python script).

Thanks!

Comment: What GIS software are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Per http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s500000004000000, you point the hyperlink settings to the particular field and use the hyperlink tool (lightning bolt) on the feature.

As for hyperlinking directly from the attribute table, I'm not sure.